# Keyboard input lang. changed when doing Process.Start() from my WF application

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, external

I have a C# Windows Forms application where I eventually start another program with

```
Process.Start()
```

For all people using my software the new program now starts with English keyboard.

Is there a way to fix that issue?

FYI, the Windows Forms app is only available in English.

Comment: if you open up an internet browser, do you have the default language german or is there maybe another browser on your system?
Or are you launching another Application that you developed? Please provide some more details :)

Comment: My default language of all programs would be German. But when I launch the external program (not my app) through my WF application, the keyboard is suddenly changed to English...

Comment: have you tried opening that app standalone to check if your keyboard changes aswell or is it just happening if you open it from your WF app?
If the latter would appear you might have to change the settings from the APP (not yours)

Comment: No thats the weird thing; it only happens when I start the other program by my WF app.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 ideas:

First one is to check ALL of your Project settings and look if you have somewhere set the english keyboard or just english language.

Second idea from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Changing-Keyboard-Layout-d50b27da):

> 1- For better performance, get the machine installed language as
>   follows: C#

```
public static InputLanguage GetInputLanguageByName(string inputName)  
{  
    foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)  
    {  
        if (lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToLower().StartsWith(inputName))  
            return lang;  
    }  
    return null;  
}
```

> 2- Set your preferred language at run time: C#

```
public void SetKeyboardLayout(InputLanguage layout)  
{  
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = layout;  
}
```